# Calling a function with default parameters which also has a callback

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Consider the example code:

```
function makeRequest(endpoint, form = {}, qs = {}, callback) {
  const exampleObject = {
    endpoint,
    form,
    qs,
  };
  callback(exampleObject);
}

makeRequest('/example', { foo: 'string' }, { bar: 'string' }, (exampleObject) => {
  console.log(exampleObject);
});
```

In the above example the following object would be logged on the console:

```
{ endpoint: '/example',
  form: { foo: 'string' },
  qs: { bar: 'string' } }
```

How can I use the defaults in `makeRequest` and still utilize the callback?  For instance, the following fails:

```
makeRequest('/example', (exampleObject) => {
  console.log(exampleObject);
});
```

Output:

```
/Users/daniel/example.js:13
  callback(exampleObject);
  ^

TypeError: callback is not a function
    at makeRequest (example.js:7:3)
    at Object.<anonymous> (example.js:10:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at loader (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:148:5)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:158:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/lib/_babel-node.js:160:24
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/lib/_babel-node.js:161:7)
```

This makes sense considering I am sending only one parameter. I am wondering how I can call `makeRequest` while taking advantage of the default parameters and still get the callback. Will I always have to pass three parameters if a callback exists?  Is there some other way to go about this so I have the option of only using the 2nd and 3rd parameters if needed and always get `exampleObject` in the callback?

Comment: Don't use callbacks. Return promises.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about [destructuring](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/05/es6-in-depth-destructuring/)?

```js
function makeRequest({ endpoint, form = {}, qs = {}, callback = () => {} }) {
  const exampleObject = {
    endpoint,
    form,
    qs,
  };

  callback(exampleObject);
}

makeRequest({
  endpoint: '/example',
  callback: (x) => console.log(x)
});
```

Comment: Something like this is exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Passing `undefined` will use the [default parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters)

```
makeRequest('/example',undefined,undefined,(exampleObject) => {
  console.log(exampleObject);
});
```

Comment: This indeed works, thanks for providing the link as well so I can read up on it.  Only question I have, is it possible to get the same results without having to pass the 2nd and 3rd `undefined` parameter?

Comment: You would have to implement/find a function overloading mechanism to be able to do it using parameters. Andreas answer is a fantastic way to do it with a object and probably more along the lines of how you are wanting to call the function.